# Add element to an array in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add multiple uids to a followers & following array. The followers/following is a field in the users model. Every usersId is associated with a post, when clicked the id goes into the current users following field and the current users id go into the followers field of the user that posted. I've googled and seen this solution but I get the error 'FirebaseError Function DocumentReference.update() requires 1 argument, but was called with 2'

I'm using ReactNative and Firestore version 7.9.0

this is my code. Thanks so much!

```
addFollows = (post) => {
 const db = firebase.firestore()
 let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
 let followingId = post.uid
 const followUserRef = db.collection('users').doc(userId)
 const followingRef =  db.collection('users').doc(followingId) 
        followUserRef.update({ 
            following: true },
            { merge: true },
        followingRef.update({ 
            followers: true },
            { merge: true }
        ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you mentioned here: "I'm trying to add multiple uids to a followers & following array".

It sounds like you just want:
userA to follow userB and update both following/followers field accordingly?

If that's the case you will want something like this:

following: [..., userBId]

followers: [..., userAId]

You need to use `FieldValue.arrayUnion`.  Trying changing this:

```
followUserRef.update({ following: true }, { merge: true });
followingRef.update({ followers: true },{ merge: true });
```

to this:

```
followUserRef.update({following: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(followingId)})
followingRef.update({followers: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(userId)})
```

This should allow you to add a new index (the followingId) to the userA "followers" array and add userId to the array of followers of the person that userA is now following.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed passing two arguments to `update()`, which is not correct.  It does not take a second parameter like `set()`, so don't pass `{merge:true}`.

```
followUserRef.update({ following: true })
followingRef.update({ followers: true })
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply...but it's not adding multiple id's, now it's just overriding the exisitng one which was the issue I was having before and came across the merge syntax.

Comment: Then you should edit the question to explain in more detail what exactly isn't working the way you expect.  Provide both the before and after contents of the documents so we can see.  You definitely can't pass two parameters as you are now, so update the code as well.

Comment: I thought I explained in detail??? I said I am trying to add multiple user ids to a field, the solution with merge was what I found on Stack Overflow...the solution suggested adding merge but that was the error I was coming across. Thank you for help though.

Comment: You have a new problem that's different than the one you described in the question.  It would be helpful if you explain in more detail so that anyone can reproduce your observations.  When you have a new question, what you're really supposed to do is post a whole new question.  Stack Overflow isn't really well equipped for going back and forth over a series of problems.